# "undefined method `file' for #<String:0x007ffaf0049a28>" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, jquery-file-upload

I'm getting this error

```
undefined method `file' for #<String:0x007ffaf0049a28>
```

when trying to display the content_type (ex. image/jpg) of a file. I'm using Carrierwave + Jquery File (both heavily modified to work together the way I want) + Amazon s3 ([click this to see what I'm doing](http://pjambet.github.io/blog/direct-upload-to-s3/)). It was working before with just carrierwave & amazon s3 but when I added the jquery file upload & direct s3, it's just not working any longer.

Can someone please help me out here? Here's what I'm doing:

```
<%= @post.attach.file.content_type %>
```

Thank you ahead of time & please let me know if you need more code/info

```
@post.attach.inspect
# https://sharebook.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/d4247713-6459-484f-9b8b-f0b7b689e8d9/picture.jpg

@post.inspect
# #<Post id: 1, name: "post title", attach: "https://domain.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/d4247713...", created_at: "2013-05-29 17:30:46", updated_at: "2013-05-29 17:30:46">
```

More info: I'm using `storage :fog`. In my carrierwave uploader, I have included

```
CarrierWave::MimeTypes process :set_content_type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you store the content type, i.e. with the `carrierwave-meta` gem?
Files don't have mime types, parts of multi part form have.
Carrierwave can get the mime_type of a file **when it is uploaded**.
So it's common to store it as meta data with the uploaded file.

Once you have `carrierwave-meta` installed and added the fields for the meta data (see [github page of carrierwave-meta](https://github.com/gzigzigzeo/carrierwave-meta) ), you can

```
  process :set_content_type
  process :store_meta
```

in your uploader and access the content_type with

```
@post.attach.content_type
```

---

You asked for a way to look up mime_types by extension.

The file extension is just a hint mainly used by Win. Unix relies on file content (magic chars etc), MacOS in meta data stored in the resource fork. Said this, there is a method to look up:

```
Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension
```

see [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Mime/Type.html#method-c-lookup_by_extension)

So the mime_type of a file stored in S3:

```
mime_type = Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(File.extension(@post.attach.inspect))
```

Comment: I took a look at the gem but it was working before I added the modified direct upload to s3 (see link in original question). In my carrierwave uploader, I have `include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type` I'm implementing this gem now, but I can't see much of what it will do different. Can't rails fecth the content_type just by going off of the file ext? @Martin

Comment: I'm using `storage :fog` btw @Martin & I'm not using "mount_uploader" in my model.. It's uploading directly to s3

Comment: I added lookup_by_extension to my answer

Comment: Something so clear & I missed it! Works like a charm. Thank you, @Martin

Answer (score 0):

A little bit hard to tell here, but it looks like your "attach"value is "#" (a string). Try doing something like ...

`<%= @post.attach.inspect %>`

to see for sure or even just ...

`<%= @post.inspect %>`

to see what they are. Is it possible that "attach" should be "attachment"?

Comment: Edited in what I got in the original question above @slabounty